# Fixing Macport for Xcode for compiling Android Firmware

Tags: android, xcode, terminal, macports, android-source

My main motive is to compile android AOSP.
For setting up the development environment I need macport and Xcode.
I have Xcode 3.2 and macport as well. 
I have xcode in /Applications/Xcode.app

When I run /usr/bin/xcode-select -print-path in terminal I get :-
/Applications/Xcode.app

Which is fine but still while running port selfupdate I keep getting errors like :

> Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute

Note I don't have a /developer folder in Xcode.app . I only have /contents folder.

Comment: The Xcode path should be `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

Comment: Ok i don't have Developer folder in Contents . All i have is CodeResources , Library , PkgInfo , Resources , version.plist , Info.plist , MacOS , PlugIns , _CodeSignature

Comment: Hmmm, you say you have Xcode 3.2, which isn't installed as an app like Xcode 4 is?  So do you have both installed?

Comment: I removed xcode 4 and now i only have Xcode 3.2 which i can run as an app. But there is no Developer directory in Contents folder.

Comment: With Xcode 3, all the developer stuff is in `/Developer`.  I think the fix here is to dump Xcode 3 and install the latest Xcode 4.  Why do you want to stick with old compilers etc?

Comment: That is what is recommended on android.com for compiling AOSP. I somehow need xcode for compiling AOSP

Comment: Ok i downloaded the latest xcode now i can get it working. Thanks but still can't get make command to run succesfully will start a new question for this. Thanks :)